# Unable to access Facebook developer account

Tags: facebook, authentication

A while ago I worked on social login integrations for my employer. To complete that task I created a Facebook developer account. Today I'm unable to access that developer account without uploading documents to prove I'm me. This occurs even though I have correct credentials and 2FA with my email.

How can I regain access to the Facebook developer account to continue maintaining our integrations? I don't have any Facebook accounts other than this one and I created the account without using real identifiers as I would like to protect my privacy. Is it no longer possible to have a developer account without verifying your identity?

Comment: facebook requires you to use your real name in any case, so there is no way around that.

Comment: you have to send them id for a dev account? that's unreasonable for a developer.

Comment: i believe i'm the admin user on the account and certainly didn't provide a real name to FB as there's no reason to. if i can't regain access, how can we maintain our integration? should someone else be forced to dox themselves?

Comment: the reason is that facebook requires it - it is their platform, so you have to live by their rules, i am afraid ;) - approval for devs is not a bad thing though, there are many app devs trying to do shady things and there is user data involed, so...

Comment: As @andyrandy said. There is nothing called Developer Account. You have a normal Facebook account and you use that. Facebook require that you only have one account. So your best bet is to contact Facebook and have your apps moved over to your real account.

Comment: Is it possible to create an account with the name of our organization rather than a particular person? It seems odd to tie an integration to a person's identity.

Comment: No. You can tie the app to a business account. But the app has to be created by user account. Which has to have your name and you are only allowed to have one user account

Comment: That's really odd considering engineers don't stay at jobs very long. Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: That why you connect it to a business in the business manager after you create the app.

Comment: _"It seems odd to tie an integration to a person's identity."_ - not really, if you don't want developers you need to ban from your platform, to open fake accounts to be able to just continue what they were doing. Ask for validation via a government issued ID, and you can keep a lot of that at bay.

Comment: The app is for a business organization and team of developers. There should be no need to place the burden on an individual. I'm just trying to recover our developer account so I can maintain an existing integration. There's no clear path to remedy the situation as the account used to integrate with FB initially is unverifiable.

Comment: "There should be no need to place the burden on an individual" - that's something you have to talk about with Facebook's customer support. Nobody here can help you about this

Comment: I would love to, but cannot find a way to communicate with them. Are you aware of a way to reach them? Was just griping about the problem. There's no clear solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is an appeal form for your case on Facebook website, you can try it with your real account to regain the access. The link is on the bottom of this page https://developers.facebook.com/appeal/

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no "real" account. The link you shared is a 404 page not found.

Comment: Seem like the link is only visible to logged in user. It means that you have to open a new account with your real identity to gain back the access.

Comment: If I create a new account, it would have no association with the FB developer apps we're using. If it's possible for a new account to gain access to our apps, can someone on our team who has a verified FB account associate their account with the applications?